# QString's in QVector memory leak

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Why when I fill the QVector as follows:

```
QVector< QPair<qint32, QString> > vector(10000000);
QString temp;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
   temp = QString::fromUtf8("Vasya");
   vector.replace(i, qMakePair(i, temp));
}
```

my program uses 470 MB of RAM, and when this:

```
QVector< QPair<qint32, QString> > vector(10000000);
QString temp2 = "Vasya";
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
{
    vector.replace(i, qMakePair(i, temp2));
}
```

it is only 90 MB of RAM?

Comment: Dewfy has answered it but you might also be interested in some further reading about Qt's implicit sharing (QString is an implicitly shared class)- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/implicit-sharing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because internally `QString` is optimized to share memory of const objects. First case needs allocate memory each time when `fromUtf8` invoked. On opposite second case always can reuse memory  from existing const `temp2`

Comment: Implicit sharing must be happening, but OP's `vector` isn't const... Perhaps copy-on-write semantics is what's happening here.